# How to disable trackpad horizontal scrolling

Tags: debian, openbox

I've recently switched from Ubuntu to Debian+Openbox on my ageing laptop. The minimalism is refreshing.

When I drag sideways with two fingers on the touchpad, this is interpreted as a horizontal scroll. Is there any way I can disable this?

Using `xev` I've identified that a two-finger horizontal drag is buttons 6 and 7. I've tried adding this line to `.Xmodmap`:

```
pointer = 1 2 3 5 4
```

which I hoped would implicitly unassign the horizontal scroll from buttons 6 and 7, but this hasn't worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian 9 should use the `libinput` driver by default (`xserver-xorg-input-libinput`), so I'm going with a solution for that one (see [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Debian_9_.22Stretch.22)).

Create a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` (create the directory if not existing) with the following content:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "HorizontalScrolling" "false"
EndSection
```

You can refer to the [libinput man page](https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput) for a detailed description of available configuration options.

If you are using the `synaptics` driver (`xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`), have a look at the relevant page of the [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Override_options_in_.2Fetc.2FX11.2Fxorg.conf.d.2Fsynaptics.conf) or the [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Configuration), the solution is almost identical.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer for a mouse

Here is an example that disable horizontal scroll  (Save the new file and reboot)

nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput-mouse-left-right.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Logitech catchall"
        MatchIsPointer  "on"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "HorizontalScrolling" "false"
EndSection
```

Other useful commands

```
xinput list
xinput list-props 15
```

Also xorg config file can be used to remap button

```
Section "InputClass"
    # ...
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 9 3 4 5 6 7 8 2"
    # OR
    Option "ButtonMapping" "a b c d e f g h i"
    # ...
EndSection
```